# Use of undeclared identifier assert Xcode

Tags: macros, llvm, assert, xcode4.5

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and LLVM 4.1 to compile some code I'm working on.

The error I am getting repeatedly is:
"error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert';

The right includes are in the header (#include cassert (I have also tried #include assert.h) but no luck.

Someone else has taken my exact code and compiled it on another computer running the same setup (Mac OSX 10.8, Xcode 4.5, LLVM 4.1).

Comment: `#include assert.h` fixed it for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same errors as yours. For my case, it turns out that there was another assert.h on the include path (CMake introduced erroneous include path for gmplib. I spotted the wrong include path when make VERBOSE=1). Not sure whether it is the same case here. LLVM itself should not have any problem with such an old header file.

Comment: Oh man, I've been trying to compile PCL (PointCloudLibrary) for a week now, and your post finally gave me the insight to look for duplicate headers. Thanks!  ... now I just have to figure out why CMake chose the wrong include path.

Answer (score 0):

Are these errors happening in [boost](http://www.boost.org/) code?  If so, you can turn off assertions (and get rid of your error) by including the following preprocessor definition in your build settings.

```
BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, I had `Always Search User Paths` turned on.